# How to assign 2 collection in nodejs using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodes

My code is looks like bellow, how to asign two collection, in my case 'User' and 'Host', btw i'm using handlebars, it always return [] or no collection in hosting variable. Please need help

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const Host = require("../models/host")

exports.index = function (req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.session.userId).exec(function (error, user) {
    const hosting = [];
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      if (user === null) {
        var err = new Error("Not authorized! Go back!");
        err.status = 400;
        return next(err);
      } else {
        console.log(user);
        const dataParse = user.toJSON();      
        Host.find({user_id:req.session.userId}).toArray(async (err, result)=>{
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          } else {
            for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
              hosting[i] = result[i];
            }
          }
        });
        console.log(hosting)
        //console.log(tes);
        return res.render("dashboard/index", {title:'dashboard', layout:'dashboard', user:dataParse,  host:hosting});
      }
    }
  });
};
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: You are using mongoose or native MongoDB driver for node.js?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing with your code functions that you are using mongoose as MongoDB package, updated your code to work

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
const User = require("../models/user");
const Host = require("../models/host")

exports.index = function (req, res, next) {
  User.findById(ObjectId(req.session.userId)).exec(function (error, user) {
    const hosting = [];
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      if (user === null) {
        var err = new Error("Not authorized! Go back!");
        err.status = 400;
        return next(err);
      } else {
        console.log(user);
        const dataParse = user.toJSON();      
        Host.find({user_id: ObjectId(req.session.userId)},(err, result)=>{
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          } else {
            for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
              hosting[i] = result[i];
            }
            console.log(hosting)
            return res.render("dashboard/index", {title:'dashboard', layout:'dashboard', user:dataParse,  host:hosting});
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
};
```